# Setting a section active while elements have focus using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, forms, css

I have a complicated form implemented on my website that has multiple sections. For each logical section I have split my form into different section elements and have styled the section using CSS. This is just a visual aid for the users to indicate the next section of the form. A simple example would be the green border around this section [HERE](https://dribbble.com/shots/2780699-Payment-Selection-Screen).

Each section can have any combination of text boxes, drop down lists, radio buttons etc. A simple example would be as below.

```
<section class="form-section">
    <p class="form-header">
        Month
    </p>

    <select id="month" name="month">
        <option value="usa">Jan</option>
        <option value="usa">Feb</option>
        <option value="usa">March</option>
        <option value="usa">April</option>
        <option value="usa">May</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

And my "form-section" CSS as below.

```
.form-section {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid rgba(156,156,156,0.1);
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    align-content:center;  
}
```

However, I want to apply styling to the "form-section" whenever the user interacts with just that sections content - e.g. when the user selects the drop down list item I want to add a drop shadow to that section. I can acheive this using the CSS :active as below, but the style is only applied while the user is clicking the section element or clicking the drop down list. The style is not kept while the user isnt pressing on the elements.

```
.form-section:active {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 5px 14px 0px rgba(156,156,156,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 5px 14px 0px rgba(156,156,156,0.5);
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 14px 0px rgba(156,156,156,0.5);
}
```

How do I achieve this or do I require Javascript to handle this?

EDIT: I also tried :target on the section but this does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

A parent element can change the style of a child element but a child element cant change the style of its parent in pure HTML/CSS:

```
#parent:hover #children { background-color: pink; } /*OK*/
#children:hover #parent { background-color: cyan; } /*Non Ok*/
```

I think you'll need a little bit of javascript.
Here is a possible way:

```
$("#child").hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().css("bakground","red");
});
```

Hope it helps.